# Jmeter Property with array of values

Tags: arrays, jmeter, jsr223, jmeter-3.2, setpropertyactionlistener

**Requirement:** Need to store 50+ values to a Jmeter property and use with idx

[image]

In the case of normal variable we can use Country_1 or Country_2.

Do we have any function to set an array of values to jmeter Property and how to get value using index?

Note: In this case,value has to be used in different thread group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Your ArrayList initialization is not correct, you should be doing something like:

   ```
   List myList = Arrays.asList('India', 'USA', 'UK')
   ```
2. There is no `putObject` method in `props` shorthand (which is basically an instance of [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class so you will need to amend your code like:

   ```
   props.put('Middle', myList)
   ```
3. Once done you will be able to access individual list members using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

   - `${__groovy(props.get('Middle').get(0),)}` - for first member
   - `${__groovy(props.get('Middle').get(1),)}` - for second member
   - `${__groovy(props.get('Middle').get(2),)}` - for third member
   - etc.

Demo:

[image: JMeter Access Array Members]

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details on using Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.